# help me !! my computer is having kernel panics and i don't know how to stop them?

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, shutdown, kernel, adobe

My computer is a Macbook Pro 13 inch from early 2014. In October of 2015 my computer started crashing. I sent it to an Apple Center to see if they could fix it. They changed a lot of things, hardware, screen, mostly everything, for this i went to the center like 3 times then the computer stars giving this crazy panic attacks, i send it to the center again and they didn't find anything, i found out that this kernel attacks are not normal! what can i do ??? how can i solve it?? They mostly appear when browsing the internet, however it does it sometimes on its own. I think it is something with Adobe but I'm not sure.

Here is the panic report:

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801631664f): "Invalid queue element linkage for 0xffffff8016a9e7c0: next 0xffffff802a564b18 next->prev 0xffffff8016a9e7c0 prev 0xffffff80f8647068 prev->next 0xffffff8016a9e7c0"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/osfmk/kern/queue.h:245
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000016000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8016200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8016100000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 
System uptime in nanoseconds: 1561745689882
last loaded kext at 903387708295: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f98cf8000, size 409600)
last unloaded kext at 108164844452: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.59 (addr 0xfffff7f9865400, size 36864)
```

Comment: -1 Please learn how to ask and post a question. Format your post properly! Remove all the 2x and 3x question marks, use proper spacing and capitalization!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've been to the Apple Store, and had repairs done on the computer, its most likely the logic board.

Typically if a computer is under warranty and a Genius at the Bar thinks the issue is related to hardware, they will replace the hardware. Kernel Panics are typically board related.

Take your laptop back to the Genius Bar, and have them run diagnostics again. You would have had a 90-day warranty for all repairs done. So, if its a board issue again they will either replace the main logic board, or triage further if its software related.